# Q1113 Ir sensor verilog and Fpga board,how to program?

Tags: fpga, proximity-sensor

I have been working with s one of the line IR sensor from sparkfun(Q113). It has 3 port a vcc, ground and signal. As I know one way to find if the object is black or white is through reflection of light. And it has a capacitor inside the sensor, and we have to charge it through the fpga and if it detect the black color then the capacitor discharges. Now I have to declare one port in fpga as input and output and find out what time it took to discharge and determine the movement of body go forward or backward.
my question is how to figure out the capacitor discharge rate so to go forward or backward and how to write code for bidirectional input. I am using Ja1 port of fpga(BASYS 2)
 code..

```
module top(
input  mclk,      // The standard clock
input  direction,  // Direction of io, 1 = set output, 0 = read input
input  data_in,    // Data to send out when direction is 1
output data_out,   // Result of input pin when direction is 0
inout  Ja1     // The i/o port to send data through
);

reg [7:0] a;
 reg [7:0] b;    

assign Ja1  = direction ? a : 1'bz;
assign data_out = b;

always @ (posedge mclk)
begin
   b <= Ja1;
   a <= data_in;
end

endmodule
```

Comment: This is a bad idea. Many digital parts won't do well with in-between voltages, as you will see while the cap is discharging.

Comment: the capacitor is in build so there is no chances of discharge..i just need help with bidirectional pin and how to find timing of capacitor dischare..